# How to get index id from table of contents

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm wondering how best to dynamically retrieve the ID of a static user using Python. I tried storing it in variable.

```
   mgmt = user-data (user-data contain below table information) 
   dynamicID = user-data.find("User ID" sp001 )
   print  dynamicID
```

This is what the table looks like

```
ID  User Name
11   sp001
16   sp002
23   sp003
```

I'm very new to Python, Any idea is always welcome :) 
    This user data is a text file so space between ID and User name is the issue..

Comment: Can you give a sample code for the same, how to open it and read?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all headers will automatically have unique id attributes generated based upon the text of the header. Note this example, in which all three headers would have the same id:

`#Header`

`#Header`

`#Header`

Results in:

```
<h1 id="header">Header</h1>
<h1 id="header_1">Header</h1>
<h1 id="header_2">Header</h1>
```

Place a marker in the document where you would like the Table of Contents to appear. Then, a nested list of all the headers in the document will replace the marker. The marker defaults to [TOC] so the following document:

[TOC]

`# Header 1`

`## Header 2`

would generate the following output:

```
<div class="toc">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#header-1">Header 1</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#header-2">Header 2</a></li>
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1 id="header-1">Header 1</h1>
<h1 id="header-2">Header 2</h1>
```

Regardless of whether a marker is found in the document (or disabled), the Table of Contents is available as an attribute (toc) on the Markdown class. This allows one to insert the Table of Contents elsewhere in their page template. For example:

```
md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=['markdown.extensions.toc'])
html = md.convert(text)
page = render_some_template(context={'body': html, 'toc': md.toc})
```